In a circular tray of radius 1, arrange coins of radius 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5 so that none of them can move independently
In a circular tray of radius $1$, arrange coins of radius $\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac15$ - at least one of each, and no other kind of coin - so that none of them can move independently, i.e. if any coin moves, then at least one other coin must simultaneously move.

By "move", I am referring to movement of a coin's centre relative to an arbitrary fixed point on the tray.
The coins are circular, rigid and smooth.
Coins must be placed flat in the tray. This is not a trick question.

For a hint, see my comments to @Weather Vane's answer.

At least one of each?  So if we do it with more than four coins, that's good?

@msh210 Correct.

@Dan Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

This does not help, but I just realized today we can pack exactly 2 x 1/2 coins  and 2 x 1/3 coins in the 1-radius circle! So nice...

May I ask, do you know if there is a unique or multiple solutions? I know in what small range to place the 1/2 coin and found some different arrangements of coins that looks promising but haven't done the calculations yet.

@Prim3numbah I found one solution. I don't know whether there are others.

I found a few promising arrangements but so far they all ended up being ~1% off.

Copy of OP's "EDIT 2": The puzzle has been solved. If you enjoyed this puzzle, then you may be interested in a related question, which I do not know the answer to.

OP's hint quickly leads to this:

 


 red = 1/2, green = 1/3, blue = 1/4, purple = 1/5


Yes, this is the solution I found. If you try to arrange the coins like this (with actual coins, or with a computer), you will initially find that there are small gaps between coins. Then push the 1/2 (red) coin down as far as possible, and all the gaps will have disappeared. (In the final arrangement, the distance between the tray's centre and the 1/2 coin's centre is somewhere between $0.34716$ and $0.34717$.)

Some people may have read my MSE question linked to in the OP, and may be wondering why this arrangement does not satisfy $n=5$ in the MSE question. The reason is that, in this arrangement, the 1/2 coin can move up while the 1/5 and the 1/4 coins also move; this kind of movement is not allowed in the MSE question.

I had assumed you were asking for a stable arrangement, where the only possible movement is rotation of the whole group within the dish.

Back to 6 coins, the simplest and tightest yet.

 But there is still a $0.005576$ gap between coins A and F.




Edit: the best fit I can find so far is still imperfect.

  There are 8 coins, but the gaps between F/H and G/H are $0.008277$
 I placed coins A to G first, so everything touches.
 Then coin H was placed touching coins B and C.




Previous: I have a close but not exact solution with 6 coins.
There didn't seem to be a solution using 4 coins (by pencil and paper trials) and I skipped 5 coins.
The best fit I can find is this:

 The tray has a radius $1.032859$



 I found this by placing the three central coins, all touching, and three more coins around them, each touching two of the first three. Then make sure that none of the middle three can 'escape', by checking its centre lies on the correct side of a line joining the other centres. Finally find the circumcircle.

 Repeating for all valid permutations, this one's circumcircle is closest to 1.0 radius.


Nice try, but not quite. The radius of the tray should be exactly $1$. (Also, it looks like your $1/3$ circle can roll along the tray wall anti-clockwise without disturbing any other coin.)

Is there an exact solution?

If by "exact solution" you mean an arrangement in which the coins perfectly fit together, with no coin being able to move independently, then yes.

Hm, yes. Rolling the 1/3 coin clockwise around the rightmost 1/5 coin from the positive x-axis, it hits the rim at the same place (approx -52°), and when rolling it anticlockwise around the same 1/5 coin from the negative x-axis it first hits the rim at about  -77°. So it isn't trapped.

Would you like a hint?

Yes, but unless it's an immediate help I can't work on this again for more than 24 hours! Perhaps your hint will allow other interested users to solve it. Presumably the hint will go in the question.

In your 8 coin attempt, change A, B and C.

Is the solution symmetrical?

Yes, my solution is symmetrical.
